# CCMenuItemImage builded with cocosbuilder can't call my methods

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

So I built a CCMenuItemImage with cocosbuilder in my cocosbuilder project and use it later in my project.
However, the responding method is never called.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Go up to the Document menu and make sure "JavaScript Controlled" is unchecked.

I was having a really hard time with this. CCBControlButtons called their selectors, but CCMenuItemImages didn't. Changed that setting and it's working now.

Comment: Thanks @fith! None of the settings was working for me. Your answer and CCBReader source code made me realize where I was failing!

Comment: Thank you. This new feature definitely should have an alert in CocosBuilder. I spend few hours trying to found a bug in code...

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide very much information that allows us to help.  However, I recently did the same thing with my app so perhaps I can give you some ideas on where to look.  First, is the CCMenu its own root node (separate file) or is it a child of a CCLayer in your CocosBuilder file?

In the first scenario, the CCMenu (and CCMenuItemImage) is a separate node file, then you would link it to your game layer code with the statement:

```
CCMenu *menu = [CCBReader nodeGraphFromFile:@"filename.ccbi" owner:self];
```

Then in the Cocosbuilder program, where you type in the name of the method the CCMenuItemImage links to, make sure you select **"Owner"** instead of "Document root".

The second scenario is where your Cocosbuilder file is a CCLayer and the CCMenu is a child of that layer, which might be a more likely scenario.  If you successfully loaded your ccb file with

```
CCScene *scene = [CCBReader sceneWithNodeGraphFromFile:@"filename.ccbi"]; (might need to double-check that one, I am not at my XCode)
```

Then, in Cocosbuilder when you type in your CCMenuItemImage method name, select **"Document Root"** to link this to your code.

Then in your game layer's code, you should have the same method as you typed into Cocosbuilder.  So if your game layer's method is:

```
-(void)pressedButton:(id)sender {
   CCLOG(@"Button pressed!");
}
```

Then you need to have the same method

```
pressedButton:
```

linked to that button in Cocosbuilder.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

well, that's happened to me too...

the solution is 
first, u have to press enter after u've typed the selector field..

secondly, u have to publish (I do more than once).

for your info.... when u saved cocosbuilder project (cmd + s), u will not save the entire project... u'll only save current scene....

so, just in case u should save and publish on every scene u worry..

last tip (i don't know the different though), I chose document root (not owner ) :D

may this tips help you bro!